# Filter wordpress post categories with jquery/ajax and pagination?

Tags: wp-query, jquery, ajax

Currently I have a website working with Wordpress and Jquery Quicksand (http://razorjack.net/quicksand/).

However I don't want to show all posts at the same time. I wish to show e.g. 6 posts and then have a pagination. And that's where I get the problem.

If I have a filter on the first page with posts, it just filters those posts, and not the ones on the other pages. [Like this (example from tutsplus.com)](http://tutorials.vinnysingh.co/quicksand/)

And that's not intuitive at all. Not being able to navigate from one page to another within a filter is just not userfriendly.

I haven't found any tutorial on this, but I found a [working example](http://stevengliebe.com/wp-playground/zipfolio/#portfolio), using quicksand. So it is possible.

So I was wondering if someone might help me, or possibly have a better solution that the working example?

The reason I added ajax in the title is because I thought it might be a better solution doing a new wp_query via ajax instead of loading all posts in multiple lists and show/hide them with the filters.